# Failed to open file. May not be a valid tile package

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm following [this sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/OfflineRoutingAndGeocoding), and when running, I get this error:

```
E/ArcGIS: java.lang.RuntimeException:Internal error exception - Failed to open file. May not be a valid tile package.
```

Here's where it fails:

```
final String extern = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
final String tpkPath = "/ArcGIS/samples/OfflineRouting/SanDiego.tpk";
TiledLayer mTileLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(extern + tpkPath);
GraphicsLayer mGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer(GraphicsLayer.RenderingMode.DYNAMIC);
```

Why can't it see my file? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `ArcGISLocalTiledLayer` needs a file URL instead of a file path. So try this:

```
TiledLayer mTileLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer("file://" + extern + tpkPath);
```

That way you're passing `file:///storage/ArcGIS/samples/OfflineRouting/SanDiego.tpk`, which should work if that file exists and if your app has requested access to external storage in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: it's still error.
E/ArcGIS: url =file:///storage/0F0C-3E0D/ArcGIS/samples/OfflineRouting/SanDiego.tpk

Comment: What does `new File("/storage/0F0C-3E0D/ArcGIS/samples/OfflineRouting/SanDiego.tpk").exists()` return? If `false`, then your app can't see that file for some reason--probably permissions or an incorrect file path. Don't forget that Android is Linux and hence file paths and names are case-sensitive. Good luck.

Comment: I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error exception - Failed to open a file. It may not be a valid tile package.

Comment: You might need to grant storage permission on the device: Settings > Apps > your app > Permissions > grant permission for Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I used this sdk

```
  implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.5.0'
```

and the code is

```
       mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
   filename = this.getResources().getString(R.string.local_tpk);
   //        We have tpk file in this path
   File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TPK");
   // create the url
   String base = storageDir + File.separator + filename;

   ArcGISTiledLayer tiledLayerBaseMap = new ArcGISTiledLayer(base);
   // set tiled layer as basemap
   Basemap basemap = new Basemap(tiledLayerBaseMap);
   // create a map with the basemap
   ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(basemap);
   // set the map to be displayed in this view
   mMapView.setMap(map);
```